# Jenkins: how to monitor multiple servers from one location

Tags: jenkins

I have multiple installation of Jenkins servers.  Is there a way to monitor all the jobs run from these servers from 1 location,htlm page, or anything else?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't set the servers up as nodes, with a single jenkins master?

Comment: To spread the load as I have many nodes already

Comment: in that case not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better way so deal with it. Our solution is to set up an html page that shows a Radiator page for each jenkins server on different html frame or iframe.

You may need to overcome the 'X-Frame-Options' protection that prevents loading a frame from a different source.

[image: Monitor jenkins servers within an html page]

For people who don't know what Jenkins Radiator plugin is, take a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins will support Rest APIs, So it is better to create a small web application (java/.Net/Php) in any technology/language, and call those APIs from different Jenkins servers as per your requirement.